# Encryption of a coulmn in a table in teradata

Tags: teradata, public-key-encryption

I have a requirement where each row in a column has to be encrypted with a public key.
 The table is a teradata table.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in Advance,
Nikhila

Comment: Implement the encryption/decryption algorithm as a UDF or consider a third party product to manage encryption and tokenization in your enterprise.

Comment: Third-party product would be Protegrity, although I don't know whether this is worth the money to encrypt just one column.